# AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop stops after about 3 hours

Tags: vb.net

This is my first post here. I need some help with my Visual Basic .NET project.

I'm making a program that runs in the background and continously plays an audio file. The project has a 10 second wav file embedded as a resource.

I was able to make it work just fine using this method:

`AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop()`

BackgroundLoop is supposed to play the audio file in the background continuously. It works fine but after about 3 hours, I noticed that it just stops. The program stays open but the audio stops looping. Is this normal? How can I prevent this from happening?

**Edit to add workaround:**

I couldn't find the reason why it was stopping the playback every 3 hours but I found a workaround.
Basically, I just added a Timer control and just kept stopping and restarting the playback every 2 hours.

`My.Computer.Audio.Stop()`

`My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Files.AudioFileName, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)`

It's working fine for now. I'll keep observing the behavior for a few hours and will report back.

Comment: That is 1024 repetitions, nice round number.  You don't have a shot at finding the unmanaged resource leak, try this on another machine.

Comment: The program doesn't consume more than 10 MB of memory. It stays the same after 2 hours. I've tested it in 3 different computers. Same results. :(

Comment: What if you use a different sound file?  Do you get a similar result?  Does it stop playing after the same number of iterations or the same amount of time?

Comment: I haven't tested this. I'm gonna try with a 20 second file. I'll report back in a few hours.